# get a process ID from a command line

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, pid

I have to launch several times an executable with different argument each time and I need to get back the process ID for each of them.

I have the used command line and I need the process ID of the process started with this command.

Following some others question here I have found this:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'evolution4.exe'" | select CommandLine
```

Which can give me the command Line use for the process started, but I now need to do a filter on the CommandLine and not on the name and Select the PID.

I tried replacing "name" by "commandLine" or "CommandLine" without result and I don't even know if it's the proper way to do. What should I put in my filter ? Does this command can be filtered by command line instead of name or pid ?

---

Edit: It seems that my problem is more about giving a path in the string of the filter than the argument which seems to be "commandLine" as I thouht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind : Answer was simple

Path must be set with double '\'.

Which lead to :

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "commandLine = 'C:\\Windows\\Explorer.exe'" | Select ProcessId
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is a straightforward "process", then you do not need to dig deep. You can get it directly from `get-process`:

```
Get-Process -Name explorer | select ID
```

In your evolution4.exe case, just check the process name:

```
Get-Process -Name evolution4 | select ID
```

Comment: Sadly I cannot, I have to do it with the commandLine as it's started by a service that can start up to 3 process simultaneously and each of them can take up to 1 hour :/

Comment: Oops, I think that I misunderstood what you told me. Actually I start 3 times the same process but the only difference between them is the arguments that I pass to each of them. Which make impossible a search by name.